# Random, Infinite Terrain Generation

Tags: c#, unity, terrain

I'm trying to generate random terrain for my game (In Unity3D, C#). All I need is water and grass. No height to it (no mountains or hills.) I'd preferably like to do it by placing individual cubes. On top of that the terrain needs to be infinite.

I've searched every where for even a hint on how to do it, but everything I found had either height to it, didn't use individual cubes (edited the terrain as a whole), or wasn't infinite.

Any help would be much appreciated! :)

EDIT: I'm looking for something somewhat similar to a game called Factorio. Here's a screenshot: http://i.ytimg.com/vi/Uns15OfPWbo/maxresdefault.jpg As you can see there is a big body of water, and a ton of land. I want to create something that randomly does that every time (random bodies of water and random land shapes). Something like Minecraft without all the height.

I've heard about something called Perlin noise, but because of a lack of tutorials and documentation, I can't figure out for the life of me on how to use it to generate random terrain.

Comment: What I'd suggest is to use one of the algorithms you found that has height, and instead of using the height, set a threshold above which height the terrain is "grass", and which under that threshold the terrain is "water".

Comment: This is quite a broad question. Could you indicate a little more precisely what sort of effect you're looking for? What have you tried, and in what way was it insufficient?

Answer (score 2):

Check noise generation algorithms like simplex or perlin noise(http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perlin_noise). By combining them you can create intricate fractal noise and by additional processing(like cutting by threshold) you will create distinctive feature maps for grass and lakes(and height maps. So you will definitely accomplish both tasks) to sample against by coordinates which is very handy if you are working with discrete elements like cubes or tiles. More information: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6091468/how-is-a-3d-perlin-noise-function-used-to-generate-terrain
There is nice question too about 2D noise generation: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8659351/2d-perlin-noise

Btw, things can't be infinite because computing is limited by storage space and datatype resolution used by coordinate system.